# How to calculate a new column using individual values of other columns in a formula?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with one column **X** that looks like this:

```
    X
1   8
2   4
3   2
4   5
5   3
6   2
7   1
8   5
```

Using the values in this column I want to create a new column **Z** that uses the following formula to calculate the new values:
[image]
So for example, to calculate Z1, the calculation would look like this:
[image]
and Z1 would have a value of 0.005.

Similarly, Z2 would have a value of -0.229 and Z3 a value of 0.107.

I hope this example makes it clear what I want to achieve for my new Z-column.
Any idea on how to solve this easily with R? Maybe in a loop?

Thankful for any tips!

Comment: What is the expected value of Z for the 8th (or last value of X)?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the calculation in numerator and denominator starts from that row till the end of the dataframe.  Is that correct? For Z1 how the numerator ends at `(2-3.75) * (5 - 3.75)` ? Shouldn't it be `(1-3.75) * (5 - 3.75)`

Comment: @Ronak Shah yes, sorry about that, you are correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following calculates what you want - at least it reproduces your first 3 given numbers:

```
(y$Z <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(y)), function(k) {
  i  <- seq_len(nrow(y))
  j <- seq_len(k)
  sum((y$X[i[-j]-k]-mean(y$X))*(y$X[i[-j]]-mean(y$X))) / sum((y$X-mean(y$X))^2)
}))
#[1]  0.00528169 -0.22887324  0.10739437  0.07746479 -0.29049296 -0.32042254
#[7]  0.14964789  0.00000000
```

It can be improved not to calculate the same values again and again.

Data:

```
y <- data.frame(X=c(8,4,2,5,3,2,1,5))
```

Comment: Yes, perfect that's it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to achieve this.

Here's the dummy data:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c(8,4,2,5,3,2,1,5))
```

Here's the while loop operation:

```
func1 <- function(x){
  len <- length(x)
  i <- 1
  z <- vector("integer",length=len)
  d <- (x - mean(x))

  while(i < length(x)){
    z[i] <- sum(d[i]*(x[i+1]-mean(x)))/(sum(d^2))
    i = i + 1
  } 
  return(z)
}
```

The output is of course the returned vector of the same length as `x`. You can then append `z` to your original data frame:

```
dat$z <- func1(dat$x)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks pretty good already, however it does not give me the right values - probably because the part x[i+1] has to change for every z. So for z1 it is correct but for z2 it needs to be x[i+2] and so on. Or did it miss this in the formula?

Comment: @User2010S can you see the new edited code does what you want? It shouldn't be hard to take it from here. Just writing the formula to your heart's desire now that you have the code syntax.

Comment: It doesn't do quite what I want it to do. But I'll try to adjust it. Thank you.